# SQL create new column based on two other columns

Tags: postgresql, null, case

In PostgreSQL, I’m trying to create a new column based on values in two other columns. If `early` or `late` are in the `Issues` column, I want to display the time delta for every row of the `delivery id`. If early or late aren’t in the issues column, I want to display a `NULL/blank` value.

What I have:

```
Delivery Id  | Issues         |  Time delta
1              late              10
2              early             -25
2              wrong address     -25
3              not confirmed     -10
4              late              8
5              not confirmed     -8
5              wrong address     -8
```

What I want:

```
Delivery Id  | Issues         |  New Time delta
1              late              10
2              early             -25
2              wrong address     -25
3              not confirmed     
4              late              8
5              not confirmed     
5              wrong address
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's no such thing as a derived column (such as in SQL Server/Oracle) in PostgreSQL.  The best you can do is to make a view with the combination of columns and derived data that you want.

Comment: how to create a new column instead?